# In Xcode, how do I know which class implement a protocol?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am wondering in Xcode, can I quickly know which classes implement some protocols?

I don't want to use search, but want to quickly identify such classes.

Comment: Go to class .h file and see if any delegate property or method signatures under @protocol block.

Comment: Why don't you want to search?

Comment: The search results include a lot of other things, such as `id<AA, BB, CC>`, which are hard to filter. @Wain

Answer (score 10):

in particular class in which protocol implement just press
 'command btn + right click of mouse' on protocol method..

it will show list of all class with implementation of this method.
and you can jump on that class by just click on it...

Answer (score 8):

You can use the Assistant Editor:

- Open the protocol that you are interested in, place the cursor inside the `@protocol` definition
- Open the Assistant Edior (<kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>option</kbd>-<kbd>return</kbd>) and from the drop down menu in the upper left, select `Protocols`:

[image]

The classes that implement the protocol will be in the list.

**Edited to add info from Rob's comment:**

Note that this only finds classes that, either in their public header or in their implementation declare that they conform to the protocol. If conformance to the protocol is declared somewhere else, those classes will not show up.

Say you have a protocol defined somewhere as

```
@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>
…
@end
```

A class with a public header `MyClass.h` like this will show up:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject <MyProtocol>
```

Also, a class that is extended in the .m file like this will show up

```
@interface MyObject () <SomeProtocol>
…
@end

@implementation MyObject 
…
@end
```

A class extension `MyClass_Extension.h` like this will not show up:

```
@interface MyObject (Extension) <SomeProtocol>
…
@end
```

Comment: Note that this only finds classes which publicly declare their conformance to the protocol.  Classes can privately conform (in a category or class extension that's not part of the public API).  The only ways to detect such cases are to examine the compiled files (e.g. with [`class-dump`](https://github.com/nygard/class-dump)) or to use the Objective-C Runtime API.