# How to show classes and structs that implement a protocol in Xcode 12+?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I would like to see a list of all the classes and structs in my Xcode workspace that implement a certain protocol, similar to how this is possible in various Java IDEs.

I found this answer stating that [it was not possible to do so in Xcode many years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22362751/viewing-class-protocol-hierarchy-in-xcode-5).

There is also [this suggestion to use the Assistant Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18118945/in-xcode-how-do-i-know-which-class-implement-a-protocol). However, this does not actually solve my problem: The Assistant Editor will only show me classes and structs that implement the protocol within the very same Swift file. That is not what I am looking for, since finding implementations within the same file is trivial. Instead I am primarily interested in implementers in all the other files within the same workspace.

Sure, I know that I can emulate this by looking in the project for strings like `: Protocol {`, but this is relies on assumptions about spacing and other things, so it is not entirely reliable. And it is more complicated than clicking on the protocol and seeing a list of the implementers similar to the callers of a function in Xcode.

[AppCode seems to have exactly what I am looking for in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22362751/viewing-class-protocol-hierarchy-in-xcode-5).

Does a feature just like this exist also in Xcode 12 or later itself?

Comment: You don't really need to make assumptions about whitespacing, since the search navigator in Xcode supports regular expressions. I don't think there is a built-in solution for this in Xcode unfortunately.

Comment: Does right-click on `Protocol`, then `Find -> Selected Symbol` give you what you need?

Comment: @DonMag It still delivers many more search results than it should - all references instead of just the definitions of structs/classes that implement the protocol. But it definitely goes in the right direction, it is at least a bit better than just a plain full text / regex search.